# Do While with IF

Tags: php

i just want data will show if `['stt']==1`

Here is the code :

```
<?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['nama']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['username']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['password']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['alamat']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['tgl_lahir']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['stt']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_daftaruser = mysql_fetch_assoc($daftaruser)); ?>
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Sorry - this code is obsolete... I'd suggest finding a newer tutorial and starting over.

Comment: 1) Stop using mysql_* functions, they're deprecated from all stable versions of PHP and removed in 7+ 2) you don't want a do while, you just want a while, then add an `if($row_daftaruser['stt'] == 1`) inside the while to check whether to display..

Comment: why don't you handle it while getting records from table?

Comment: Why don't you just put `WHERE stt = 1` in the query?

Comment: I use dreamweaver,so i dont understand, im before use if funtion in php, but i forget if in php you must give endif not like python.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
<?php do { ?>
    <?php if($row_daftaruser['stt'] == 1): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['nama']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['username']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['password']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['alamat']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['tgl_lahir']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_daftaruser['stt']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php } while ($row_daftaruser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($daftaruser)); ?>
```

This code will only display values if stt is equal to 1.

Also, use mysqli not mysql because it mysql is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you write the query this way?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE stt = 1;
```